# Styling JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON value that has multiple values separated by a comma. Is there a way to have that rendered in the dom as a selection dropdown input?

Here is a more detailed view of my markup.

HTML

```
 <h1>JSON Grid Edit</h1>

     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dt display" id="json-table-edit" contenteditable="true" onKeyUp="editValue(this.id);">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="25%">Setting</th>
          <th width="75%">Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Setting</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

JSON

```
     {
      "allconfig": {
         "card.inserted": {
         "value": "Inserted, Not Inserted",
     },
        "card.cisproc": {
        "value": "Processed",
      }
     }
    }
```

JQUERY

```
$.getJSON('json/ione-edit.json', function (data) {
 var newJson = [];
 var myJson = data;
 $.each(myJson.allconfig, function (key, value) {
     var rowArray = [];
     rowArray.push(key);
     $.each(myJson.allconfig[key], function (key1, value1) {
         rowArray.push(value1);
     });
     newJson.push(rowArray);
 });
 $('#json-table-edit').dataTable({
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "bStateSave": true,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "bProcessing": true,
     "oLanguage": {
         "sLengthMenu": ' <select>' + '<option value="10" selected="selected">Filter</option>' + '<option value="10">10</option>' + '<option value="20">20</option>' + '<option value="30">30</option>' + '<option value="40">40</option>' + '<option value="50">50</option>' + '<option value="-1">All</option>' + '</select>'
     },
     "aaData": newJson
 });
```

Comment: If you have control of the JSON itself, why not change the comma delimited string into an array of strings? Let the JSON parser do what it was meant to do.

Comment: I tried making it an array of strings, but that didn't render a select element

Comment: You still need to create the `<select>` DOM element. There are many ways to do that and it has no direct relationship to the structure of your JSON. You may want to back up a few steps, start with [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the split() method. split(",") will give you an array of separate strings for each coma separated entity. You can then use the jQuery .each() method to iterate over the array and append each string to the DOM wrapped in `<option>` tags.

something like this:

```
 var data = {
  "allconfig": {
     "card.inserted": {
     "value": "Inserted, Not Inserted",
 },
    "card.cisproc": {
    "value": "Processed",
  }
 }
}

var options = (data.allconfig["card.inserted"]["value"]).split(",");

$("body").append("<select id='select'></select>");
//I am appending this to the body, but you can change body to
// whatever element/class/id you want 


$(options).each(function() {
  $("#select").append("<option>"+this+"</option>");
});
//I have also given the select an id so this code can be used on pages that have multiple select elements
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbBEb/3/)

Comment: the select element isn't created though. There is no markup for the tbody.

Comment: no this answer assumes you have a select element already. I will update this to include the creation of the select input.

Comment: Also I am not sure where the tbody comes in, as your question does not seem to require tables of any sort. If you could elaborate maybe we can get more specific to you context.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the plain Javascript method [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

You'll need to `split` the value string, which will then turn the comma-seperated string into an array. Then you'll need to run over the array to make your `select` dropdown.

Something like this inside of your JSON return function (not exactly these variable names, just an example to show you the idea):

```
$('#SelectContainer').html('<select name="mySelect">');
var options = value.split(',');
for (counter=0; counter < options.length; counter++)
{
    $('#SelectContainer').append('<option value="' + options[counter] + '">' + options[counter] + '</option>');
}
$('#SelectContainer').append('</select>');
```

Comment: depending on where I position that code, i get an error that ReferenceError: value is not defined or TypeError: value.split is not a function

Comment: @ndesign11 Like @Jeremythuff said, can you please show us more of your code? It seems that we aren't understanding your full situation correctly. Essentially, you need to either declare the `<select>` tag in your HTML beforehand, or create it using the JS as I've shown here. As I mentioned, this code isn't using the variable names you need to use; I gave you the link to the docs so that you can figure out your own exact code on your own.

Comment: @ndesign11 that is probably because your variable is not a string. next time use value = value.toString(); before spliting it.

"The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings."